# Why does a markov matrix always have an eigenvalue of 1?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, markov-chains

According to [this lectuere](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~knill/teaching/math19b_2011/handouts/lecture33.pdf):

> A Markov matrix A always has an eigenvalue 1

because

> For the transpose of matrix $A^T$, the sum of the row vectors is equal to 1. The matrix $A^T$ therefore has the eigenvector [1;1;...;1]

I don't really understand this. Why does the sum of row vectors adding to 1 make the matrix have an eigenvalue of 1?

Answer (score 2):

Assume $A=\begin{pmatrix} a_{11}&a_{12}&...&a_{1n}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&...&a_{2n}\\.\\.\\.\\a_{n1}&a_{n2}&...&a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}$ is a matrix with all rows summing up to 1 and $v=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\.\\.\\.\\1\end{pmatrix}$. Therefore:$$Av=\begin{pmatrix} a_{11}&a_{12}&...&a_{1n}\\a_{21}&a_{22}&...&a_{2n}\\.\\.\\.\\a_{n1}&a_{n2}&...&a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\.\\.\\.\\1\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a_{11}+a_{12}+...+a_{1n}\\a_{21}+a_{22}+...+a_{2n}\\.\\.\\.\\a_{n1}+a_{n2}+...+a_{nn}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\.\\.\\.\\1\end{pmatrix}=v$$where the latter equality is true according to our assumption. So $\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\\.\\.\\.\\1\end{pmatrix}$ is an eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue 1.

Comment: Where did the eigenvector [1;...;1] come from?

Comment: I only took such a vector and showed that is an eigenvector

Comment: @Juan Really the vector [1;...;1] has been chosen so that the condition on the matrix (that the sum of the elements in each row equals $1$) can be expressed in matrix form. When you express it, you get the calculation from this answer. It is similar to converting a system of linear equations to its matrix form, except that you don't have unknowns but $1$'s.

Answer (score 1):

A more general statement is available.

> If $A$ is an $n$-by-$n$ matrix with complex entries, then $A$ has row sums equal to one if and only if $Ae = e$, in which $e$ denotes the all-ones vector.

*Proof*. Notice that 
\begin{align*}
Ae = e \Longleftrightarrow \sum_{j=1}^n a_{ij}=1,~i=1,\dots,n.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

If you multiply out A*[1;1;...;1], you get the vector [$\sum_{j=1}^n a_{1j}$;$\sum_{j=1}^n a_{2j}$;...;$\sum_{j=1}^n a_{nj}$]. If all these numbers are the same, then [1;1;...;1] was an eigenvector.

Comment: Where did the eigenvector [1;...;1] come from?

Comment: @Juan If you like, you can just say direct observation. In the probability context, though, if you have a row stochastic matrix $P$ and a column vector $u$, $P$ represents a certain Markov chain $X_n$. In particular, $(Pu)_i=E[u(X_1) \mid X_0=i]$. If $u$ is constant then it is easy to see that $Pu$ must also be constant (the expected value of a constant function will not change with time no matter where in the state space you start).